# How to show many to many relationship data in laravel8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have many to many relationship data into the database using below code fetching data in controller :

```
public function index(){
        $data = Singer::with('songs')->get();
        return view('singers_index')->with('singer_data',$data);
    }
```

data getting as below format :

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Praful","created_at":"2022-08-29T12:51:03.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-08-29T12:51:03.000000Z","songs":[{"id":1,"title":"Chocolate karne laga","created_at":"2022-08-29T12:45:15.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-08-29T12:45:15.000000Z","pivot":{"singer_id":1,"song_id":1}},{"id":2,"title":"Chocolate Dance laga","created_at":"2022-08-29T12:48:12.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-08-29T12:48:12.000000Z","pivot":{"singer_id":1,"song_id":2}}]},{"id":2,"name":"Mayuresh","created_at":"2022-08-29T14:42:40.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-08-29T14:42:40.000000Z","songs":[{"id":3,"title":"Baby ko base pasand hai","created_at":"2022-08-29T14:42:07.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-08-29T14:42:07.000000Z","pivot":{"singer_id":2,"song_id":3}}]}]
```

I am not getting how to set multiple songs into the table using comma seperator

```
 @foreach($singer_data as $all_data)
<tr>
    <td>{{$all_data->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$all_data->user->title}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Not getting how to add that songs with comma seperator into the view.

I have added **belongsToMany** relationship with both models i.e. Song and Singer

```
class Singer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function songs(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Song::class,'singer_songs');
    }
}

class Song extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function singer(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Singer::class,'singer_songs');
    }
}
```

If anyone have idea how to display into the view with comma seperator. Please help me in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various methods for pulling data and displaying it, such as `pluck()` and `implode()`:

```
public function index(){
  return view('singers_index', [
    'singers' => Singer::with('songs')->get()
  ]);
}
```

Then in your `.blade.php` file:

```
@foreach($singers as $singer)
  <td>{{ $singer->songs->pluck('title')->implode(', ') }}</td>
  <!-- OR -->
  <td>{{ $singer->songs->implode('title', ', ') }}</td>
  <td>{{ $singer->user ? $singer->user->name : 'No User' }}</td>
@endforeach
```

The `->pluck('title')` returns a Collection of Song Titles, like:

```
collect(['Chocolate Dance laga', 'Baby ko base pasand hai'])
```

And `->implode(', ')` returns them as a comma-separated string:

```
Chocolate Dance laga, Baby ko base pasand hai
```

`->implode('title', ', ')` is alternative syntax, and skips the `pluck()` method, but outputs the same comma-separated string.

Documentation:

[`->pluck()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-pluck)

[`->implode()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-implode)

Answer (score 0):

you can use laravel accesser. I think it's the best clean way

```
class Singer extends Model
{
  public function getAllSongsAttribute()
    {
        return $this->songs->implode("title", ",");
    }
}
```

now use this attribute on singer model:

```
$singer->all_songs ;
```